# Is [methodology]'s methodology worthy of burnination?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've just now discovered the tag [methodology](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodology).  It's associated with only 8 questions, and it has no tag wiki.  Not only does the name sound like it could be off-topic, but the lack of a wiki really doesn't help.  Stack Overflow has the same tag *with* a wiki, and it may help with deciding on this:

> A methodology is usually a guideline system for solving a problem,
>   with specific components such as phases, tasks, methods, techniques
>   and tools.

Another piece of evidence is two (now-deleted) old questions that were *only* using this tag.  One was more fitting for Programmers SE, and the other just contained pseudocode.  The remaining 8 questions are unlike these, though.  But that tag still doesn't fit with them nor with the site.

Burninate?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this picture before...

Comment: *It's the call of Trogdor the Burninator!!!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this tag doesn't belong, so I'll slowly kill it off.  Since it's not a very large one, I don't think contacting SE for immediate burnination is necessary.  It'll also give me a chance to give more attention and/or improve these few questions.

**UPDATE:** The [methodology](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodology) tag is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  I don't see anything that the current questions have in common.  Furthermore, I can't think of any justifiable use of such a tag on Code Review.